# verificador de que un string sea diferente a ""

Tags: java

tengo un `string` el cual lo inicialice con ""

```
String dato="";
```

Como puedo verificar que la variable dato sea diferente a ""?

he intentado:

```
try{
     if(dato == null){
         System.out.println("sin nada");
     }
     System.out.println("no vacío");
}catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

}
```

pero me sigue dando esa excepcion, que método de la clase String puedo implementar, o alguién tiene alguna solución?

Disculpas ya lo pude solucionar, tenia otro código antes de la sentencia if lo que me lanzaba esa exepción

Comment: Que es lo que quieres conseguir? Porque dices la variable `dato` pero aqui estas utilizando otra `if(telfF == null)`

Comment: envés de telfF seria "dato" eso lo puse xq estaba probando en otro proyecto que cree pero ya lo solucione.. he tenido que antes me imprima el contenido de una ubicación inexistente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edición I:**

Como menciona en comentarios @SJuan76, la clase `String` tiene el método `isEmpty()` que devuelve `true` cuando la cadena mide 0 `(length() = 0)`.
De esta forma los dos métodos propuestos quedarían como:

```
public boolean isEmpty(String str){
    return str == null || str.isEmpty();
}
```

y

```
public boolean isEmpty(String str){
    return str == null || str.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

**Respuesta Original**

Este método devuelve true si el String str no es null y no está vacío.

```
public boolean isEmpty(String str){
    return str == null || str.equals("");
}
```

Se puede ser más estricto eliminando espacios al inicio y al final para evitar que una cadena como "  " sea interpretada como no vacía.

```
public boolean isEmpty(String str){
    return str == null || str.trim().equals("");
}
```

Comment: No es mala respuesta, pero las últimas (ya desde hace algún tiempo) versiones de Java tienen un método *String.isEmpty()* que es mucho más descriptivo (= fácil de leer) que *equals("")*

Comment: @SJuan76 Agregando la variante con `isEmpty()`

Comment: Creo que hay un error en `return str == null && str.trim().isEmpty()` y en `return str == null && str.trim().equals("")` ya que si la variable es nula procede a la otra sentencia en que llama un método donde la variable es nula y lanzaría un NullPointerException, por lo que creo que debería ser `return str != null && str.isEmpty()` e igual con el otro método, en cambio con el `||` está bien ;p

Comment: Sí en realidad es un error de && x ||. Lo habia hecho al revés y cuando lo corregí me quedó el and sin cambiar. Gracias!